# Display percent encoded emoji to html

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8

I have a percent encoded URI coming from an ajax result.

```
%F0%9F%91%9A%F0%9F%A7%9E%F0%9F%A4%B6%F0%9F%8F%BB%F0%9F%8E%85%F0%9F%8F%BC%F0%9F%91%9A%F0%9F%A7%9E
```

I would like to display the percent encoded URI in an html page

the encoded URI above is

But the display only shows the same percent encoded URI

The ajax request is done using jQuery

What function should I use to decode the percent encoded URI and display those emoji.

Comment: does my answer helped?

Comment: @Tushar It didn't work. I'm still looking

Comment: can you show you ajax code and how you are creating HTML from it?

Comment: @Tushar actually it did work I just needed to add urlDecode on my server side. I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `decodeURI` to decode your string and get the emoji's.

```js
console.log(decodeURI('%F0%9F%91%9A%F0%9F%A7%9E%F0%9F%A4%B6%F0%9F%8F%BB%F0%9F%8E%85%F0%9F%8F%BC%F0%9F%91%9A%F0%9F%A7%9E'))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Jquery html](https://api.jquery.com/html/) works on setting up emoji.
you need to decode your URI encoded string first.

```
$('#emoji').html(decodeURI('%F0%9F%91%9A%F0%9F%A7%9E%F0%9F%A4%B6%F0%9F%8F%BB%F0%9F%8E%85%F0%9F%8F%BC%F0%9F%91%9A%F0%9F%A7%9E'));
```